# Can I share my Banshee playlists between two computers using Dropbox?

Tags: banshee, dropbox

I have my music collection stored on Drobox, and I use two different computers running Ubuntu and Banshee to access that collection.

While the music files themselves are easily accessed using Banshee on both computers, having playlists synchronize between both computers isn't.

Assuming that I don't open Banshee at the same time on both computers, is it possibly to store the playlists in a Dropbox folder so that they are accessible and synced between both computers?